# how to write trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am developing an online videos web application. I want to restrict accessing videos in a particular time. I wrote a trigger but I am encountering problems with incorrect syntax. Please help me.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_Update_Employee ON [CourseTopic]
FOR SELECT AS

BEGIN

  DECLARE @week int, @hour int
      SET @week = DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())
      SET @hour = DATEPART(hour, GETDATE())
  IF @week = 3 OR @hour > 10 AND @hour > 10
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK tran
    PRINT 'class timing is over you can not watch this video at this time.'
  END 
END
```

Comment: What database are you using? What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: There is no such thing as a SELECT trigger. Also, I don't think you should solve this particular problem on the database at all.

Comment: then plase tell me how to achive this

Answer (score 3):

You can't have SELECT triggers for SQL Server (looks like that dialect). Triggers fire for logged data changes only (UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT)

You'd achieve this by a view or a stored procedure or some other code/client check.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest moving your business logic to a stored procedure instead.

Something like this to suit your business requirements:

```
 CREATE PROC GetVideos

 AS
     DECLARE @Now smalldatetime = GETDATE();

     SELECT ID, URL FROM Videos
     WHERE  DATEPART(dw, @Now) != 3 
     AND    DATEPART(hour, @Now) <= 10;
```